# How to set the lifetime of the IP address with ip addr

Tags: networking, ip-address

I'm trying to learn the `ip addr` command because it seems it's on every distro now. The problem is that, while I can successfully add and remove addresses, I can't change the lifetime of them, i.e; **set them permanently.**

[image: screenshot]

Adding `forever` at the end like the man page suggests doesn't quite work. Omitting it, however, does.

```
[✘] ip addr replace 10.0.0.37/22 dev ens160 permanent
[✘] ip addr replace 10.0.0.37/22 dev ens160 forever
[✘] ip addr replace 10.0.0.37/22 dev ens160 -1
[✘] ip addr replace 10.0.0.37/22 dev ens160 \-1
[✘] ip addr replace 10.0.0.37/22 dev ens160 0
[✔︎] ip addr replace 10.0.0.37/22 dev ens160 valid_lft forever
[✔︎] ip addr replace 10.0.0.37/22 dev ens160
```

At least it seems it should work because changes are lost on restart. On the screenshot above there's a CentOS VM which was configured with the wrong static IP address and thus on restart it takes over from the changes made with the `ip addr` command.

**UPDATE** It seems I wasn't clear enough, sorry about that. The goal is to change a statically configured IP address (by **Anaconda**) therefore change the lifetime to "stick" (forever). The problem is that it's overwritten on reboot.

So it's both to change an address and change its lifetime.

Comment: This question is not clear on whether the goal is to reconfigure a statically assigned IP address or set an IP address lifetime.

Comment: `ip` is only intended to make changes to the current ip configuration. If you want to make these changes "permanent" (they should reappear on next boot), you need to change them in whatever does the configuration (usually `/etc/network/interfaces`, network manager, or systemd; I have no idea how Anaconda configures an IP address...) and not with `ip`. So the real task is to figure out what Anaconda does to set this address (or maybe it happens somewhere else?).